# Higher version of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

I've been studying statistics for a while now, and honestly, I've been struggling to gain an intuition for both the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) and the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) up to this point. Now, I just came across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Relation_to_the_law_of_large_numbers) paragraph which describes both theorems as first and second-order asymptotic expansions. Unfortunately, the paragraph is very short and quite vague (probably by intention). In particular it doesn't state the underlying asymptotic scale $\{ \phi_k \}$ and stops after the second order.

So, here is my (also very vague) interpretation: Let $(X_1, X_2, \dots)$ be i. i. d. random variables with finite $1$st, $2$nd, ... , $k$th momentum $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_k$. We set $\bar{X}_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and we assume that there is an asymptotic expansion
$$
\bar{X}_n \sim \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \,n^{\frac{1}{k}},
$$
where $A_k$ are random variables and convergence is meant in distribution. I thought that $ \left\{ n^{\frac{1}{k}} \right\}_k$ is a reasonable choice for the asymptotic scale. If I made no mistake, in general, we should have
$$
A_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bar{X}_n^{k}, \qquad  \text{where} \quad \bar{X}_n^{k}:=n^{\frac{1}{k(k-1)}} \left( \bar{X}_n^{k-1}-A_{k-1} \right).
$$
The LLN then says that $A_1 =  \mu_1$, so it is a deterministic random variable. And the CLT says that $A_2$ has law $\mathcal{N}(0,\mu_2)$.

Assuming that I am not completely off-track, can we say something about
$$
A_3 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bar{X}^3_n , \qquad  \text{where} \quad \bar{X}^3_n = \frac{\left( \bar{X}_n- n\mu_1  - \sqrt{n}A_2 \right)}{\sqrt[3]{n}}
$$ and beyond?

Comment: Having studied probability theory for forty years now I see that WP article for the first time. Why don't you take a standard reference that contains CLT and LLN and try to understand those? Not every hobby probabilist writes such important WP articles that we must understand them to know what those theorems are saying.

Comment: I did not say that one has to understand the paragraph to understand the CLT. Its just an approach that I haven't seen in my previous studies and which looks interesting. I found it nice to see a derivation of both theorems from a single principle and just wanted to know whether this is a developed idea..

Comment: I don’t think your asymptotic expansions make sense here, your sum might be infinite even for finite $n$.

Comment: The best intuition for the law of large numbers comes from calculating the exact mean and variance of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Comment: @Michael I had a typo in the last line, is this what you meant? Otherwise I'm not sure.. We only need that $\bar{X}_n-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} A_k n^{1/k} = O( n^{1/{N}})$

Comment: Can you use linearity of expectation, and facts about variances of sums of pairwise uncorrelated random variables, to calculate the mean and variances I mentioned?

Comment: In case this is not clear, I know how to prove both theorems and how to use them. There is exactly one question in my post. If you have an answer to that you're welcome to post it.

Comment: You already have good responses to your question. I again note that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_kn^{1/k}$ does not makes sense as a structure.  I also observe that the Wikipedia paragraph is not suggesting that asymptotic expansions are proofs of anything. I also note that if you want to define something by recursion such as $X_n^k$, then you need to start by clearly defining a base case, say, $k=1$ or $k=0$.

Comment: I feel like your comment about the asymptotic is the only on-topic statement so far. So, could you please elaborate why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: What happens if $A_k\geq 1$ for all $k$? Then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_kn^{1/k}=\infty$. In general that sum does not make sense.

Comment: It's an asymptotic series, see my previous comment

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: Its a formal series. Given an asymptotic scale we can compute the coefficients by taking the limit of the truncated series and thus derive the asymptotic behaviour with respect to the scale.. The recursion starts with the sample mean at k=1

Comment: But I am getting more and more convinced that the scale is not the right one... Or its indeed all nonsense, who knows

Comment: You might use $\{X_i\}$ i.i.d. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ as a test case. Since the linear combination of i.i.d. Gaussians is again Gaussian, you may need your $A_i$ coefficients to be zero for $i\geq 3$. Now if you want your results to apply to any distribution with finite mean and variance, you may be forced to accept these coefficients are always zero. Since we are only talking about convergence in distribution, I'm not sure the "subtracting out" idea is well posed anyway.